# Returning data from async call that takes multiple params in Swift function

Tags: swift

I was trying to create a post method so I could reuse it further in my code.
I saw this example [Returning data from async call in Swift function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function) that gives partial solution to my problem but don't know how to call the function once I define it.

This is the function I am trying to call:

```
class func postRequest(url: URL, request: URLRequest, saveCookie: Bool, completionHandler: @escaping (_ postRequestStatus: [String:Any]) -> ()) {
        let session = URLSession.shared
        //So now no need of type conversion
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {
            (data, response, error) in
            func displayError(_ error: String) {
                print(error)
            }

            /* GUARD: Was there an error? */
            guard (error == nil) else {
                displayError("There was an error with your request: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            guard let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode, statusCode >= 200 && statusCode <= 299 else {
                displayError("Your request returned a status code other than 2xx!")
                return
            }

            /* GUARD: Was there any data returned? */
            guard let data = data else {
                displayError("No data was returned by the request!")
                return
            }

            /* Since the incoming cookies will be stored in one of the header fields in the HTTP Response,parse through the header fields to find the cookie field and save the data */
            if saveCookie{
                let httpResponse: HTTPURLResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
                let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: httpResponse.allHeaderFields as! [String : String], for: (response?.url!)!)
                HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookies(cookies as [AnyObject] as! [HTTPCookie], for: response?.url!, mainDocumentURL: nil)
            }

            let json: [String:Any]?
            do
            {
                json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
            }
            catch
            {
                displayError("Could not parse the data as JSON: '\(data)'")
                return
            }

            guard let server_response = json else
            {
                displayError("Could not parse the data as JSON: '\(data)'")
                return
            }

            if let userID = server_response["UserID"] as? Int64 {
                print(userID)
                completionHandler(server_response)
            }else{
                displayError("Username or password incorrect.")
            }
        }
        return task.resume()
    }
```

This is the caller function:

```
class func loginPostRequest(post_data: [String:Any], completionHandler: @escaping (_ postRequestStatus: [String:Any]) -> ()){

    let url = URL(string: HTTPConstant.Login.Url)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    var paramString = ""
    for (key, value) in post_data
    {
        paramString = paramString + (key) + "=" + (value as! String) + "&"
    }
    request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: .utf8)
    //in the line below I get the error message, extra argument "request" in call.  
postRequest(url: url, request: request, saveCookie: true, completionHandler: { postRequestStatus in
        completionHandler(postRequestStatus)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make `loginPostRequest` return `NSDictionary` because you are making async call with what you need is to create completion block same way you have create with `postRequest` method also from Swift 3 you need to use `URLRequest` with mutable `var` object instead of `NSMutableURLRequest` you need to also change the `postRequest` function's request argument type to `URLRequest` so latter no need to convert `NSMutableURLRequest` to `URLRequest` and use Swift type dictionary instead of `NSDictionary`

```
class func loginPostRequest(post_data: [String:Any], completionHandler: @escaping (_ postRequestStatus: [String:Any]) -> ()){

    let url = URL(string: HTTPConstant.Login.Url)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    var paramString = ""
    for (key, value) in post_data
    {
        paramString = paramString + (key as! String) + "=" + (value as! String) + "&"
    }
    request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: .utf8)
    postRequest(url: url, request: request, saveCookie: true, completionHandler: { postRequestStatus in
         completionHandler(postRequestStatus)
    })
}
```

Now simply changed the argument type of request to `URLRequest` from `NSMutableURLRequest` in method `postRequest`

```
class func postRequest(url: URL, request: URLRequest, saveCookie: Bool, completionHandler: @escaping (_ postRequestStatus: [String:Any]) -> ()) {
    let session = URLSession.shared
    //So now no need of type conversion
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
       func displayError(_ error: String) {
            print(error)
        }

        /* GUARD: Was there an error? */
        guard (error == nil) else {
            displayError("There was an error with your request: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        guard let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode, statusCode >= 200 && statusCode <= 299 else {
            displayError("Your request returned a status code other than 2xx!")
            return
        }

        /* GUARD: Was there any data returned? */
        guard let data = data else {
            displayError("No data was returned by the request!")
            return
        }

        /* Since the incoming cookies will be stored in one of the header fields in the HTTP Response,parse through the header fields to find the cookie field and save the data */
        if saveCookie{
            let httpResponse: HTTPURLResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
            let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: httpResponse.allHeaderFields as! [String : String], for: (response?.url!)!)
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookies(cookies as [AnyObject] as! [HTTPCookie], for: response?.url!, mainDocumentURL: nil)
        }

        let json: [String:Any]?
        do
        {
            json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
        }
        catch
        {
            displayError("Could not parse the data as JSON: '\(data)'")
            return
        }

        guard let server_response = json else
        {
            displayError("Could not parse the data as JSON: '\(data)'")
            return
        }

        if let userID = server_response["UserID"] as? Int64 {
            print(userID)
            completionHandler(server_response)
        }else{
            displayError("Username or password incorrect.")
        }
    }
    return task.resume()
}
```

Now when you call this `loginPostRequest` you are having response in completion block of it.

Comment: I followed this approach, but I am getting an error in line: postRequest(url: url, request: yourUrlRequest, saveCookie: true, completionHandler: { postRequestStatus in
         completionHandler(postRequestStatus)
    }).
Error message: Extra argument "request' in call.

Comment: I updated both fnction and error is in"loginPostRequest" function.

Comment: @Ra'salGhul Can you show the new declaration of method `postRequest` that you have changed from my solution?

Comment: Attached above is the new declaration of method postRequest.

Comment: @Ra'salGhul As of your `loginPostRequest` method is class method you need to also make `postRequest` as `class` so either add prefix class in both method or remove it from `loginPostRequest` and you all set to go also check carefully that I have replace all NSDictionary with `[String:Any]` you need to also do the same

Comment: I added    (data, response, error) in this line: 
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
As you had removed  (data, response, error)  and it was throwing an error.

Comment: That was a mistake. I Corrected it. New to stack overflow. Really appreciate  your help. 
Can you help me with this one too?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993129/returning-data-from-async-call-that-takes-multiple-params-in-swift-function/43993365?noredirect=1#comment75058529_43993365

Comment: @Ra'salGhul Let me check that mate :), If I have solution I will post it

Comment: Here it is/ Sorry for the typo. Thankful for your help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44015515/how-to-create-a-function-that-returns-the-return-value-from-async-call

Comment: @Ra'salGhul  Let me check that mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Functions that receive a closure as parameter can be called like any other functions:

```
postRequest(url: yourUrlObject, request: yourUrlRequest, saveCookie: true/false, completionHandler: { postRequestStatus in
    // ... code that will run once the request is done
})
```

If the closure is the last parameter you can pass it outside the parenthesis:

```
postRequest(url: yourUrlObject, request: yourUrlRequest, saveCookie: true/false) { postRequestStatus in
    // ... code that will run once the request is done
})
```

You can check the Swift book to learn more about [closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94) and [functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158).

By the way, your `postRequest` method looks weird, I haven't checked deeply into it, but for instance I believe although `url` is one of the parameters it isn't actually used. Some other answer pointed other problems into that function.

Comment: I realized that I don't need to pass url as a param, thank you for pointing that out.  But I followed this approach, but I am getting an error in line: postRequest(url: url, request: yourUrlRequest, saveCookie: true, completionHandler: { postRequestStatus in completionHandler(postRequestStatus) }). Error message: Extra argument "request' in call

Comment: And your `postRequest` function didn't changed? I don't get the same error here.

Comment: Attached above is the new declaration of method postRequest. I just changed NSDictionary to [String:Any]

Comment: I did a Playground with your updated code, I still don't get any errors.