# How to create a function that returns the return value from async call.

Tags: swift

So I have this POST function.

```
class func postRequest(request: URLRequest, saveCookie: Bool, completionHandler: @escaping (_ postRequestStatus: [String:Any]) -> ()) {
    let session = URLSession.shared
    //So now no need of type conversion
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {
        (data, response, error) in
        func displayError(_ error: String) {
            print(error)
        }

        /* GUARD: Was there an error? */
        guard (error == nil) else {
            displayError("There was an error with your request: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        guard let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode, statusCode >= 200 && statusCode <= 299 else {
            displayError("Your request returned a status code other than 2xx!")
            return
        }

        /* GUARD: Was there any data returned? */
        guard let data = data else {
            displayError("No data was returned by the request!")
            return
        }

        /* Since the incoming cookies will be stored in one of the header fields in the HTTP Response,parse through the header fields to find the cookie field and save the data */
        if saveCookie{
            let httpResponse: HTTPURLResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
            let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: httpResponse.allHeaderFields as! [String : String], for: (response?.url!)!)
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookies(cookies as [AnyObject] as! [HTTPCookie], for: response?.url!, mainDocumentURL: nil)
        }

        let json: [String:Any]?
        do
        {
            json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
        }
        catch
        {
            displayError("Could not parse the data as JSON: '\(data)'")
            return
        }

        guard let server_response = json else
        {
            displayError("Could not parse the data as JSON: '\(data)'")
            return
        }

        if let userID = server_response["UserID"] as? Int64 {
            print(userID)
            completionHandler(server_response)
        }else{
            displayError("Username or password incorrect.")
        }
    }
    return task.resume()
}
```

Now I call this post function via this function:

```
class func loginPostRequest(post_data: [String:String], completionHandler: @escaping (_ postRequestStatus: [String:Any]) -> ()){
    let url = URL(string: HTTPConstant.Login.Url)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    var paramString = ""
    for (key, value) in post_data
    {
        paramString = paramString + (key) + "=" + (value) + "&"
    }
    request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: .utf8)
    postRequest(request: request, saveCookie: true, completionHandler: { postRequestStatus in
        completionHandler(postRequestStatus)
    })
}
```

The above metntioned functions are in the same class. Now I want to write a function in a different class such that I can just call loginPostRequest() with and get the [String:Any] as result. Something like this:

```
 var post_data = [String:String]()
    post_data["username"] = "Email"
    post_data["password"] = "Password"
data :[String:Any] = HTTPRequests.loginPostRequest(post_data);
```

<-- 
--> How do update other function so I could achieve above "data" as a return value without have to worry about completion handler here.

Comment: @ebby94 Yes you can, you can wait on a semaphore that's unlocked in the completion handler, then you can return the result (also set in the completion handler)

Comment: @Alexander Didn't know about that. Will look into it. Thanks for the info though :)

Comment: @Ra'salGhul what is the problem with completionHandler of `loginPostRequest` that approach is also good why you want with return

Comment: @Alexander I'm a bit confused. Are you saying that I can **return** a value from a function which is asynchronous? I know that we can get the value in a completion handler, but I didn't know we can return a value. I tried searching for what you said and I couldn't find something related. Any links or explanation on what you meant will be much appreciated.

Comment: @ebby94 No, you use the completion handler to assign to a local variable (captured by the completion handler closure, but defined in the scope of the sync function), and then return that variable once the async call completes (as indicated by the signalling of a semaphore)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is pretty specific, but I'll provide a more generalized solution, so that it may help others who stumble upon this, too. If you have follow-up questions in implementing this, feel free to ask.

Firstly, if your goal is to get synchronous behavior, use synchronous methods. Many libraries offer functions in both asynchronous and synchronous variants. There's no point for them to perform extra work to make a call asynchronous, only for you to do even more work to make a synchronous wrapping for it.

You can convert any asynchronous call that's meant to use a completion handle to a synchronous call that returns a value. Just follow this pattern:

```
func synchronousFunction(_ someInput: Input, timeout: DispatchTime? = nil) -> Result {
    var result: Result?

    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    asynchronousFunction(input, completionHandler: { _result in
        result = _result
        semaphore.signal()
        // signalling the semaphore indicates the async function is done,
        // that `result` is set, and that `synchronousFunction` can return it.
    })

    // Wait for signal from completion handler, up to `timeout`, if it's set
    if let timeout = timeout  { semaphore.wait(timeout: timeout) }
    else { semaphore.wait() }


    if let result = result { return result }
    else { fatalError("The completion handler didn't assign to `result`.") }
}
```

You can also use `DispatchWallTime` if `DispatchTime` isn't accurate enough for you. Or remove the timeout logic altogether, if you're sure the async task will complete.

Comment: *Firstly, when possible, use synchronous methods* is a bad suggestion. Quite the contrary use **asynchronous** methods as much as possible. Waiting / polling – which blocks the current thread – is more expensive / less efficient than asynchronous code  – which is usually dispatched to a background thread. And what are the *synchronous methods* of `URLSession` you are talking about? I don't know any.

Comment: @vadian I meant if your goal is to have synchronous behavior, use synchronous methods. And I was mistaken about URLSession

Comment: The *goal* is often an alibi for lacking knowledge / understanding of asynchronous data processing. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var post_data = [String:String]()
post_data["Email"] = "isername@hotmail.com"
post_data["Password"] = "password1234"
HTTPRequests.loginPostRequest(post_data: post_data, completionHandler: { postRequestStatus in
    let data = postRequestStatus
    print(data)
})
```

Comment: Hi there, please make sure to explain your code snippet. Why does this work?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different ways of doing this, since I've written this a solution was given, but I figure there are more ways than one to skin a cat.. so why not have options.

I'm just taking a guess without trying to implement this myself, but one way to do cross thread communication would be using protocols. This requires associated classes (delegates) to conform to methods/variables. The "manager" class can uses these required methods/vars to pass data to the delegate. So maybe something like this? (if this is in fact what you're trying to achieve, absence of using a handler from outside classes?):

**Protocol/"Manager":**

```
//protocol, required vars/func a delegate must have (conform to)
protocol HTTPRequestDelegate {
    var post_data: [String: String] { get }
    func httpRequestDelegate(receivedData: [String: Any])
}

//manager class, acts on delegate via protocol methods/vars
class HTTPRequest: NSObject {  //Im just using the NSObject super

    //declare a property the delegate can access and assign as themself
    var delegate: HTTPRequestDelegate? {
        didSet {
            //once a delegate assigns itself as the delegate, execute the desired class func   
            guard let delegate = delegate else { return }
            HTTPRequest.loginPostRequest(post_data: delegate.post_data, delegate: delegate)
        }
    }


    class func postRequest(request: URLRequest, saveCookie: Bool, completionHandler: @escaping (_ postRequestStatus: [String:Any]) -> ()) {
        //class setup
    }


    // Since you are using class func's, add a parameter to bring in the delegate's of the class
    class func loginPostRequest(post_data: [String:String], delegate: HTTPRequestDelegate) {
        let url:  URL = URL(string: "theURL")!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        postRequest(request: request, saveCookie: true, completionHandler: { postRequestStatus in
                    // once the data has been received, send the data to the delegate via protocol func
                    delegate.httpRequestDelegate(receivedData: postRequestStatus)
        })
    }
}
```

**Delegate class:**

```
//delegate class, the class you want to receiver to send info to  
class FooClass: NSObject, HTTPRequestDelegate {

    var post_data: [String: String] { return postData }
    var postData = [String: String]()
    var data: [String: Any]?
    let requestManager = HTTPRequest()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.postData["username"] = "Email"
        self.postData["password"] = "Password"
        requestManager.delegate = self
    }

    func httpRequestDelegate(receivedData: [String : Any]) {
        //when the httpRequest class receives the data, it will call this call this function and send the info to the delegate(s) class as parameters.
        data = receivedData
    }
}
```